# How to use shell script pipe json to curl to sent slack message

Tags: json, shell, curl, jq

I have a monitor API (for example: www.example.com/monitor ) well return system status in JSON format, for example:

```
{
   "foo" : 1000,
   "bar" : 100
}
```

I want to use curl to get system status from this API and pipe to Slack

The following is my current script.

```sh
status=$(curl "http://www.xample.com/monitor/status" )
slackWebHook="https://hooks.slack.com/services/xxxxx/xxxxx/xxxxx"

function sentSlack () {
 json_template='{
    channel:    $channel,
    username:   $username,
    text:       $text,
    icon_emoji: $icon_emoji,
    attachments: [$attachments]
  }'

  jq -n --arg channel  "#unicorn_log" \
       --arg username "Kuasa Search Report" \
       --arg text     "${msg}"\
       --arg icon_emoji "chart_with_upwards_trend" \
       --arg attachments "${status}" "$json_template" |
       curl -i -X POST --data-urlencode "$(</dev/stdin)"  ${slackWebHook}

}

sentSlack
```

I always get **invalid_payload** , because the status be escaped.

```
{
   \"foo\" : 1000,
   \"bar\" : 100
}
```

How can I pass JSON to Slack payload correctly?

Comment: Not important to your question, but as an aside, `function name() {` is merging two different syntax variants -- the legacy ksh syntax `function name {` and the POSIX-compliant syntax `name() {` -- in a combination that isn't compatible with *either* legacy ksh or the POSIX sh standard. (Moreover, bash doesn't honor the special meaning `function` had in ksh, controlling whether `declare`d variables were function-local by default). Better to stick to one or the other; see https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`--arg key value` treats value as a string. Since a string containing literal `"`s needs to have escapes added to be valid in JSON, that's what `jq` does.

`--argjson key value`, by contrast, parses `value` as JSON text; which appears to be what you want to do here.

Change `--arg attachments "$status"` to `--argjson attachments "$status"`.

Comment: thanks, I change to --argjson and echo the result echo $(</dev/stdin), and It seems correct , but still get invalid_payload

Comment: Can you get curl working by hand, so the only question is how to make jq's output match a known-good example? Otherwise we're potentially in a space where someone would need to know Slack's API, not just jq or bash.

Comment: @howie, ...that said, a question about the API could well be a good fit for the site -- if you did end up coming to the conclusion that you're stuck in understanding how to use curl to submit this message even after factoring `jq` and `bash`-specific parts out of the question, feel free to edit the question to focus on that outstanding issue; I'll re-open it and delete this answer.

Comment: ok~ I will check out what wrong with slack API~:D